# Use of Maps in Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

If you register a table and one of its fields is a map (`extra` in this case“) the following statement works just fine:

```
SELECT f1, f2 FROM customers WHERE extra['sportPrefs'] = 'Football';
```

Now try to reference a key that does not exist in the map.

```
SELECT f1, f2 FROM customers WHERE extra['moviePrefs'] = 'Action';
```

You will get an NPE and the job exits. This would be OK if there was a way to check whether a particular key exists in a map. Unfortunately, I have not found a way. Check for `IS NOT NULL` does not work. Without this feature maps in Flink SQL are pretty useless. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Please consider filing a bug report (including the Flink version you are using). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you do describe was a bug that is described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8617).

It will be fixed in the next Flink version 1.5.0 that will be released next month.